# A way to do multiple statements per bash test && statement

Tags: bash

Does anyone know of a way to execute multiple statements within a bash test?  So if I use:

```
[[ $Var = 1 ]] && echo "yes-1" || echo "no-1"
```

And set `Var=1` then output is: `yes-1`
If i set `Var=2` then output is: `no-1`

And this work as I expected. But If i try to add another statement to execute in the mix and it doesn't work:

```
[[ $Var = 1 ]] && echo "yes-1";echo "yes-2" || echo "no-1";echo "no-2"
```

Which makes sense as bash sees the command ending at; but... this is not what I want.

I've tried grouping and evals and functions and have had failures and successes but I'd really just like to do is have this work on one line.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simple command grouping should work; the syntax can be a little tricky though.

```
[[ $Var = 1 ]] && { echo "yes-1"; echo "yes-2"; } || { echo "no-1"; echo "no-2"; }
```

A few things to note:

1. Heed @tvm's advice about using an `if-then-else` statement if you do anything more complicated.
2. *Every* command inside the braces needs to be terminated with a semi-colon, even the last one.
3. Each brace must be separated from the surrounding text by spaces on both sides. Braces don't cause word breaks in `bash`, so "{echo" is a single word, "{ echo" is a brace followed by the word "echo".

Comment: Thanks I had tried something like this but must have missed the ";" at the end of the second statement.

Comment: I gave you the correct answer because the ";" at the end of each statement makes it work with either () subshell or {} grouping.

Comment: IMO, command grouping is better, in most cases. e.g. if you want to exit a script when something fails you can do `foocmd || { echo foo failed; exit 1; }` and it will print a diagnostic and exit. If you use subshells for grouping, only the subshell itself will exit, not the scipt, which is almost certainly not the intended effect.

Answer (score 12):

Consider using regular IF THEN ELSE statement. Use of && and || is justified in simple test such as this:

```
[[ -z "$PATH" ]] && echo 'Disaster, PATH is empty!' || echo 'Everything ok!'
```

But, consider following command:

```
true && true && true && false && true || echo 'False!'
False!
```

OR

```
true && { echo true; false ; } || { echo false; true ; }
true
false
```

Anytime a non-zero exit status is returned, command after || is executed. As you can see, even command grouping doesn't help.

Execution in subshell behaves in similar manner:

```
true && ( true; echo true; true; false ) || ( true; echo true; false )
true
true
```

Just use regular IF, if you need proper IF behavior.

Comment: You may be right but grouping does appear to work. I generally use the if-else-fi construct, but like the short sweetness of [[]]&&|| and on quick and easy statements sometimes I have 2 involved and the if-else-fi takes up a lot of code for a quick and dirty [[]]&&|| with multiple statements.

Answer (score 2):

Use subshells:

```
$ Var=1; [[ $Var = 1 ]] && ( echo "yes-1";echo "yes-2" ) || ( echo "no-1";echo "no-2"; )
yes-1
yes-2

$ Var=2; [[ $Var = 1 ]] && ( echo "yes-1";echo "yes-2" ) || ( echo "no-1";echo "no-2"; )
no-1
no-2
```

Comment: Yes this works and I swear I tried something like it.  I did note that you do not need the ";" that you have after the "no-2" echo to have it work but having it doesn't hurt and makes it obvious if you change the "()" to "{}" then you need the ";".

Comment: I bumped your count up for getting me going down the path.  As stated to "chepner" with ";" at the end of each statement either () subshell or {} grouping will work!

Comment: @pn1dude agree, i always use `;` at the end of all my commands in a subshell or grouping just for consistency (`"special cases aren't special enough to break the rules"` :P). The only reason i didn't this time is because i was in a rush and i copy/paste your code and simply i forgot :P I'm glad i helped, good luck

Comment: I think I failed to do the ";" at the end of my grouping try and then I just assumed it didn't work...  But yes you got me to try it again.  Yes it helps as I get sick of log if statements for quick and dirty stuff.

Comment: Subshell is ok if don't need to assign/increment variable, otherwise you must use command grouping as in chepner's answer, because the variables form subshell won't propagate back.