# How to do conditional aliases in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I want to alias mv/rm to 'git mv'/'git rm' ONLY IF current path is a git work copy. Otherwise mv/rm is just normal mv/rm.

Could zsh achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot (or really should not) be done with aliases. Aliases are just replaced by their value before execution and thus do not provide any control structures.

If you need more control, functions are much better suited:

```
function rm mv () {
    if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree &> /dev/null
    then
        git $0 "$@"
    else
        command $0 "$@"
    fi
}
```

This creates two functions - `rm` and `mv` - with the same body. Depending on being inside a work-tree either `git` is called with the used command name (`$0`) or the command itself is called.

It is important to use `command` (which explicitly calls the external command from `$PATH` instead of a function or alias) or to call the executables with a their complete path (`/bin/$0`), else the function will be called recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add two improvements to the accepted answer

- The accepted answer does not work if the file to move or remove is not tracked, for this `git ls-files --error-unmatch` is a better option, because it will check both things (being in a repo and the first file argument being tracked)
- I like to use `&&` and `||`

However, as pointed out in the comment below `&&` and `||` do not behave like an if statement. Indeed, `a && b || c` is equivalent `{a && b} || c` and will execute `c` also when `a` is true but `b` is false (it is equivalent to two if statements one inside the other), while an if statement will never execute `c` when `a` is false, no matter the outcome of `b`.

So choose either option depending on the wanted behaviour:

- With `&&` and `||`:

  ```
  function rm mv () {
      git ls-files --error-unmatch $1 && git $0 "$@" || command $0 -iv "$@"
  }
  ```

  choose this option if you want to silently move a git file with `mv` if git mv fails (even though git ls-files is true), for example this will still work if you are trying to move a file outside the repository
- With an `if` statement:

  ```
  function rm mv () {
      if git ls-files --error-unmatch $1
      then
          git $0 "$@"
      else
          command $0 -iv "$@"
      fi
  }
  ```

  choose this option if you want to keep git and non git files separated, for example it will fail if you try to move a git file outside the repository

Comment: NB: `&&-||` is not a true ternary expression, and does not behave the same as `if-then-else`. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039494.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

```
alias cd='() {if [[ -f $1 ]]; then cd $(dirname $1); else cd $1; fi}'
```